# How can I get the average amount of columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table in my database called `rating`:

```
id   user_id    rating

1    2          5
2    3          5
3    1          2
4    1          1
5    1          5
6    2          4
```

The point is that I don't know the exact amount of the entries. It can be 100 entries or just 4. 
For example when I want to know the average rating for the user with `user_id = 1` what should I do in the SQL statement?

I've a known parameter `$user_id` to get the rating of each user.

Let's say the average rating of `user_id = 1` is `2.6` I've a problem because I need to round it to the next higher number which is 3.

So this is to complicated for me. I've tried this here but it's not working:

```
$total_rating = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rating WHERE user_id = $user_id
$rating = what know?
```

I'm not that good in SQL so I would be very thankful if you can help me!

Comment: `ceil(avg(rating))`, not `count(*)`.

Comment: Just use `SELECT CEIL(AVG(rating)) FROM rating WHERE user_id = $user_id`. That will give you what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating)) AS 'Average Rating'
FROM rating
WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
```

That should do it!